# Сбивается Image в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

При запуски игры на телефонах высокого разрешения, меню не работает. Настройки Canvas и Image на скинах  .
[image: Canvas]

[image: Сама ошибка]

[image]

Comment: Screen space юзлесс. Только overlay.